# Mongoose: doesn't put _id to embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var Embedded = new Schema({
   some: String
})

var Main = new Schema({
  other: String,
  em: [Embedded]
})
```

On Main.save({other:1, em:[{some:2}]}) `mongoose` adds object {other:1, em:[{some:2,"_id" : ObjectId("51f6d89a6269170000000039")}]} to the database.

Can I say to mongoose not to add _id to embedded document?

Comment: Hey @adsurbum did my answer work? If so I'd be happy if you accepted it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When defining a schema you can specify options as a second parameter. Set _id to false to disable auto _id.

```
var Embedded = new Schema({
  some: String
}, {
  _id: false
})
```

See [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id).

Comment: How about the damn exact opposite? I've spent the last half a day trying to get the _id to be set